# php: remove <p>, </p>, <br> and <br /> from beginning and end of string

Tags: php, xhtml

help...

```
$chars = " \t\n\r\0\x0B";
$pattern = '('.implode('|',array_map('preg_quote',array('<p>','</p>','<br />','<br>'))).')'."\b";
$data = trim(preg_replace('~'.$pattern.'$~i','',preg_replace('~^'.$pattern.'~i','',trim($data,$chars))),$chars);
```

That code is set to remove all `<p>,</p>,<br> and <br />` from the beginning and end of a html string. But it is no working quite alright. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use something like this:

```
$subpattern = '(<(br|p)[^>]*>)';

$pattern = '~(^'.$subpattern.'|'.$subpattern.'$)~i';
```

Then, all you need to do is:

```
$data = trim(preg_replace($pattern, '', $data), $chars);
```

Comment: great! although, i had to modify the subpattern to: $subpattern = '(</?(br|p) ?/?[^>]*>)';